# GetComponentInChildren is getting Sibling's Children too

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a folder hierarchy like below. `Circle`s have script for drawing the circles, and `OuterCircle` & `InnerCircle` have scripts for instantiating and narrowing scripts.

```
MainParent
  - OuterCircle (instantiate + narrow)
    - Circle (draw)
  -  InnerCircle
    - Circle
```

In the first go (destroying + initialising), narrowing script works as expected. But after initiating new circle gameObjects, it is grabbing one gameObject at a time.

---

Narrowing Script *(added on both OuterCircle and InnerCircle)*:

```
 public BuildCircleMesh circleScript;

 void Start () {
    circleScript = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<BuildCircleMesh> ();
 }

 void Update () {
    if (circleScript == null) {
      circleScript = GameObject.Find("GameCircle").GetComponentInChildren<BuildCircleMesh>();
    }

    circleScript.innerRadius = circleScript.innerRadius - 5 * Time.deltaTime;
 }
```

If the narrowing script is running in `OuterCircle` and `InnerCircle` gameObject (parents), shouldn't GetComponentInChildren work independently so they behave for their own child rather than grabbing each others? Because I think the problem is both folder starts grabbing other parent's child *(and if I deactivate one parent, it works perfectly as well - so the problem is when I have two and **I suspect it starts grabbing sibling's children**)*.

Comment: GetComponentInChildren only gets Components of his own children or from itself, the problem can't be this. Where is the GameObject with the "GameCircle" name? I'm not understand why you made this `GameObject.Find("GameCircle")`.

Comment: Do not do the "find" instead have each child add it self to the parent:
transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent <BuildCircleMesh> () addChild (this).;
uses this philosophy, and please avoid "find" in the Updates